# Bootstrap: login form in dropdown navbar menu

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created login form in dropdown navbar item. It is working cool, even with responsive ui, but there is one problem. 
When I resize desktop browser to phone size, I can still open menu, focus username, password input and press submit. But on phone, I can expand login position, but when I touch inputs or button - submenu hides. Have you any ideas how can I fix it?

working code: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/4324/

```
 <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Loguj<strong class="caret"></strong></a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                        <form action="http://localhost/fabrykagier/auth/login" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                            <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="identity" size="30" placeholder="e-mail">
                            <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="password" placeholder="hasło" size="30">
                            <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">
                            <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Pamiętaj mnie</label>

                            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Zaloguj">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Ok, I decided to give that login <li> class visible-desktop and create second login li with class hidden-desktop, that is link to login page :-)

Answer (score 1):

this is  probably what you need:

```
$(function(){
  // Fix input element click problem
  $('.dropdown input, .dropdown label').click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

source: http://mifsud.me/adding-dropdown-login-form-bootstraps-navbar/